# I tried to upload a csv file (from my desktop) to create a table in Bigquery; however, the table does not appear under my project

Tags: google-bigquery

---The steps I used to upload .csv file were:

1. upload, browse, select .csv from my desktop
2. select auto detect schema and input parameters
3. create table

One possible cause of the initial malfunction was that my .csv was a zipfile; which did not automatically load in the usual manner, and I canceled the process.  After several failed attempts to upload the zip file I tried to upload a different .csv and was not been able to create a table then or since.

---

I located the error message (HTTP409) which states the table already exists, so I've tried changing the write preference to "overwrite" as well as "append to the table" but the processing function takes several minutes and does not complete.  I'm unable to create any tables.

Comment: I think we are probably going to want to see exactly what steps you are performing and what logs are produced.  You may want to update the original post with as much detail as possible to help the community assist you in understanding the nature of the puzzle.

Comment: Did you see the job details in the job history tab?